How to save workout route if the watch app exited unexpectly
I'm using HKWorkoutRouteBuider to create route in my watch os app
self.routeBuilder?.insertRouteData(locations, completion: { success, error in })
This is how to insert the locations to the route builder
And when workout session stopped
builder.endCollection(withEnd: date) { [weak self] success, error in
    self?.builder?.finishWorkout(completion: { [weak self] workout, error in
        guard let workout = workout else {
            return
        }
        self?.routeBuilder?.finishRoute(with: workout, metadata: nil, completion: { route, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

If I killed the app during workout, the workout the synced to healkit in few minutes, but the route is lost. I checked the WorkOutDoors, they can save the route even app was killed
How to acheive the same behavior in WorkOutDoors
